# SQL 2008 R2 SSRS export to Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, export-to-excel, export-to-csv, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a `SSRS report` that works fine but has an issue exporting to `Excel` or `CSV` formats.
I tried exporting to excel but errors out saying it has *more than 256 columns*.
So I was hoping I could just export it to CSV format. But with CSV I noticed that it adds up unwanted `'textbox1', textbox2` etc and also does not display the header that I actually added. Instead it would display the actual field name as header. I figured I could edit the individual properties to show Header Names. But the textboxes in the exported sheet is still an issue.

On the other hand I was trying if I could export it to excel but limit 100 columns per sheet or rest of the columns after 256 to next sheet that would be great.
I saw few posts on google breaking by group. But in my case I do not have columns to be grouped. Only need to break first 100 columns to sheet1 and next 100 to sheet2 or the 256 columns to sheet1 and the rest to next sheet.
No luck in both ways. Could you please help with this?

> Error: "Excel Rendering Extension: Number of columns exceeds the
>   maximum possible columns per sheet in this format; Columns Requested:
>   264, Max Columns: 256"

Comment: Are you using a matrix to pivot your data to get a dynamic number of columns? You could then use **ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY YourPivotedField)** in the SQL to add a number to each type. Then uses a list to beak at every 200 or so fields **Group BY CINT(COL_NUM / 200)**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very common issue when you work with `SSRS 2008 R2`. If your reports have columns more than 256, then it doesn't export to Excel.

Try to understand this technically. Technicality is, `SSRS reports` by default install `2003 office component` on `Report server`. When your report give a call to export data into excel, then report server internally give a call to office component. And if you will see, then you will find that in `office 2003`, you have **maximum of 256 columns in a sheet**. So in any case, you cannot export more than that using your existing infrastructure.

**Options:**

1. Move to `SSRS 2012` or `SSRS 2014`. This will also update your office component to `2007` or `2010` where you can export up to **16,384 columns**.
2. If you cannot move to new infrastructure then you have to `break-down` your reports such that it never exceeds to **`256 columns`**.
3. Export to other formats like `PDF`. But when you do so, then it disturbs the UI. So I don't see this as a very feasible solution.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Based on the various posts on web I understood that 2008 R2  by default renders in excel 2003-2007. BUt ERight

Comment: @GSR Do you have any other problem, then post it here. If it helped then accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: Hey submitted the previous comment accidentally hitting enter.                      Actually except for xml format all others (pdf/csv/excel) are throwing the same error. For the #1 you suggested. Right now we have office 365 and SQL server 2008 R2 and SSRS 2008 R2. upgrading only my SSRS to 2012/2014 would that help ?  Or the SQL server also has to be 2012 ?

Comment: Also on a separate note, I found this work around here and trying to see if this works. Have you tried the column grouping ? https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/32f28407-e1ca-457e-92fd-d292e32dde4e/limit-no-of-columns-in-ssrs-matrix-report?forum=sqlreportingservices&prof=required

Comment: In order to upgrade SSRS, you have to upgrade SQL Server first.. Second for column grouping, yes we did that...